# Is it possible to clear a list box via a combo box in delphi

Tags: database, delphi, combobox, listbox

I'm trying to find a way to display items in a ListBox by using a ComboBox to search through a database. I have done that, but is there a way to clear the ListBox when I choose another item in the ComboBox?

Here's the code I have so far:

```pascal
with dmAfritours do
begin
  while not(tblReserves.Eof) do
  begin
    if cbb1.Items[cbb1.ItemIndex]=tblReserves['Province'] then
    begin
      //lst1.Clear;
      lst1.Items.Add(tblReserves['ReserveName'])
    end;
    tblReserves.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What does your code do now?  What is the problem? You need to give more details so we can help.

Comment: Have you looked at TDBLookUpListBox and TDBLookUpComboBox?

Comment: @mirtheil So basically when the program runs, the user clicks on the combo box and selects an item from there. This code uses that string from the combo box and searches through the database and the list box displays all the information from the database. This code works but it does not execute if I choose another item in the combo box. It displays the same information from the previous item in the list box. I want the list box to display the information simultaneously with the search from the combo box if that makes sense.

Comment: How about putting `lst1.Clear` before the `while` loop?

Comment: BTW, calling `cbb1.Items[cbb1.ItemIndex]` repeatly is just bad. Assign the value to a variable first.

Comment: @W.Chang tried putting it before the while loop. Same result, I know its bad coding to do that but I was lazy to assign it to a variable lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `Clear()` the `ListBox` before entering the `while` loop.  Also, make sure you are calling `tblReserves.First;` before entering the `while` loop, too.

Something like this should be working fine:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.cbb1Select(Sender: TObject);
var
  Province: string;
begin
  Province := cbb1.Items[cbb1.ItemIndex];
  lst1.Clear;

  with dmAfritours do
  begin
    tblReserves.First;
    while not tblReserves.Eof do
    begin
      // alternatively, consider using the DataSet's Filter property instead...
      if tblReserves['Province'] = Province then
      begin
        lst1.Items.Add(tblReserves['ReserveName']);
      end;
      tblReserves.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```